# glTexImage2D crashing program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glut

Here is my code:

```
int h, w, c;
unsigned char* img = stbi_load("bricks.jpg", &w, &h, &c, 0);
if (img == NULL) {
    printf("Error in loading the image\n");
}
printf("Image loaded with width of %d, height of %d, and %d channels", w, h, c);

GLuint txtr = 0;
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGenTextures(1, &txtr);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, txtr);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
```

For some reason, my window no longer opens when I un-comment `glTexImage2D`. `w` and `h` are both calculated by `stbi_load`, which is a part of the `stb_image.h` library. Where is my mistake here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jpg image consists of 3 color channels (`GL_RGB`) and `stbi_load` returns a tightly packed image. The number of bytes of the of the image buffer (`img`) is `w * h * 3`.

By default OpenGL assumes that the start of each row of an image is aligned 4 bytes. This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4. Since the image has 3 color channels, and is tightly packed the start of a row is possibly misaligned.
So the size of the image buffer is assumed to by `aligne(w*3, 4) * h`.

The crash is caused, because [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml). access the buffer out of bounds.

Change the the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter to 1, before specifying the two-dimensional texture image (`glTexImage2D`):

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
```

Note, `glPixelStorei` sets a global state, which is kept until it is changed again.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the source of your problem here is a mismatch between number of channels in the pixmap loaded by `stbi_load` method and number of channels in the original image format you passed as 7'th argument into `glTexImage2D` method.
Basically, `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, INTERNAL_FORMAT, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, SOURCE_FORMAT, SOURCE_TYPE, SOURCE_PIXMAP_DATA)` causes OpenGL to create a 2D texture that has internal pixel representation of `INTERNAL_FORMAT`, that has is `WIDTH` pixels wide and `HEIGH` pixels high from the source pixmap `SOURCE_PIXMAP_DATA` which consists of a sequence of pixels encoded in `SOURCE_FORMAT`, `SOURCE_TYPE`.

I think `stbi_load` read a 3 channel, 24 byte per pixel (`GL_RGB`, `GL_BYTE`) image from a file, but you tell OpenGL to treat the source pixmap as 4 channel, 32 byte per pixel (`GL_RGBA`, `GL_BYTE`) image. It's incorrect.

You should either check `c` variable before specifying the source pixmap format or request `stbi_load` to load 4-color-channel image by assigning `4` to its 4'th argument (damn, a lot of 4's here).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was apparently with `GL_RGBA`. I changed it to `GL_RGB`, and the program no longer crashes; though, I do wonder why it was crashing in the first place.

Comment: You're reading an image with 3 channels, but tell OpenGL that your image data has 4 channels. 4 > 3 so OpenGL will read outside the bounds of the image buffer. For this code to be robust you should determine the `format` parameter (which you statically set to `GL_RGB(A)` in your code) from the value of `c`. 1→GL_RED (or GL_LUMINANCE if you're using pre OpenGL-3), 2→GL_RG, 3→GL_RGB, 4→GL_RGBA